PostgreSQL error: permission denied for schema public
tengo una duda respecto a la configuracion de permisos en PostgreSQL. Es mi primera vez con ORM y no se muchas cosas aún. Agradecería algo de apoyo de alguien familiarizado con el tema.
Cree mi base de datos con filess.io, realizo la conexión con 'sequelize-typescript' y utilizo como herramienta DBeaver(uso Windows).
Filess.io me da el user, password, host y url para realizar la conexion, la cual se establece correctamente.
A la hora de crear la tabla, desde VSC, en la consola me figura el siguiente error:
original: error: permission denied for schema public
Investigando y preguntando al chat, al parecer desde PostgreSQL v.+15 en adelante, el schema public ya no tiene los permisos para crear. Hay que otorgarselo. Cuando intento hacerlo, me dice que no tengo permiso para hacer eso. Al parecer tengo que ingresar como un superusuario y dar esos permisos, algo asi entiendo. Cosa que no se hacer y no encuentro información que me sirva, o al menos que entienda.
Alguien sabrá orientarme, o le habrá pasado algo similar?
Cómo hacen hoy en día programadores con postgreSQL para crear una tabla?
Adjunto codigo:
db.ts

import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import colors from 'colors';
import { Sequelize } from 'sequelize-typescript';

dotenv.config();

const db = new Sequelize(process.env.DATABASE_URL, {
  models: [__dirname + '/../models/**/*.ts'],
  schema: 'public',
});

export async function connectDB() {
  try {
    await db.authenticate();
    db.sync();
    console.log(colors.magenta.bold('Conection successfull to DB'));
  } catch (error) {
    // console.log(error);
    console.log(colors.red.bold('Have an error connecting to the DB'));
  }
}

export default db;

Product.model.ts

import { Table, Model, Column, DataType } from 'sequelize-typescript';

@Table({
  tableName: 'products',
})
class Product extends Model {
  @Column({
    type: DataType.STRING(100),
  })
  name: string;

  @Column({
    type: DataType.FLOAT(6, 2),
  })
  price: number;

  @Column({
    type: DataType.BOOLEAN,
  })
  availability: boolean;
}

export default Product;

Mensaje de error:
 original: error: permission denied for schema public
      at Parser.parseErrorMessage (C:\Users\lautaro\Desktop\VSC\Curso React + Typescript\pern\rest-api-node-ts-server\node_modules\pg-protocol\src\parser.ts:369:69)
      at Parser.handlePacket (C:\Users\lautaro\Desktop\VSC\Curso React + Typescript\pern\rest-api-node-ts-server\node_modules\pg-protocol\src\parser.ts:188:21)
      at Parser.parse (C:\Users\lautaro\Desktop\VSC\Curso React + Typescript\pern\rest-api-node-ts-server\node_modules\pg-protocol\src\parser.ts:103:30)
      at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\lautaro\Desktop\VSC\Curso React + Typescript\pern\rest-api-node-ts-server\node_modules\pg-protocol\src\index.ts:7:48)
      at Socket.emit (node:events:517:28)
      at Socket.emit (node:domain:489:12)
      at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:335:12)
      at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:308:9)
      at Socket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:245:10)
      at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23) {
    length: 99,
    severity: 'ERROR',
    code: '42501',
    detail: undefined,
    hint: undefined,
    position: '28',
    internalPosition: undefined,
    internalQuery: undefined,
    where: undefined,
    schema: undefined,
    table: undefined,
    column: undefined,
    dataType: undefined,
    constraint: undefined,
    file: 'aclchk.c',
    line: '3650',
    routine: 'aclcheck_error',
    sql: 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "public"."products" ("id"   SERIAL , "name" VARCHAR(100), "price" FLOAT, "availability" BOOLEAN, "createdAt" TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL, "updatedAt" TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY ("id"));',
    parameters: undefined
  },
  sql: 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "public"."products" ("id"   SERIAL , "name" VARCHAR(100), "price" FLOAT, "availability" BOOLEAN, "createdAt" TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL, "updatedAt" TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY ("id"));',
  parameters: {}
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...


Hola Lautaro, bienvenido, la pregunta/respuesta debe ser autocontenida, esto es que no dependa de imágenes o enlaces, te sugiero que la edites, y la adaptes a los requerimientos del sitio, para que no sea cerrada, y evitar recibir votos negativos,

¡Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Te invito a hacer el [tour].Por favor no publiques código o mensajes de error/trazas de pila en imágenes, publica directamente el texto del código, el texto de los errores y los stack traces. Esto hace que sea menos complicado, para quien quiera ayudarte, investigar sobre el tema y hacer sus propias pruebas/adaptaciones al código, al escribir una respuesta y de esa forma aumenta tus posibilidades de encontrar la ayuda que buscas. Un saludo.

Puedes conectarte como superusuario mediante la aplicación psql en el shell del equipo donde está corriendo el motor, para ello debes editar el archivo     pg_hba.conf. En el cual la linea que contiene los permisos para conectarte por Ipv4 debería quedarte de la siguiente forma:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust

Luego puedes ejecutar psql con estos parametros para acceder compo superusuario:
psql -h 127.0.0.1 -U postgres <base de datos>

Y desde la consola asignar los permisos que consideres necesarios.
Saludos
